# Generating sin/cos on Virtex7 with Vivado

Tags: fpga, xilinx, trigonometry, vivado

I am trying to implement a QAM modulator in SystemVerilog on a Virtex 7 with Xilinx Vivado and I am stuck with the generation of the sin and cos of the local oscillator.

More specifically, I have as inputs the I and Q signals (3 bits each) and I have to multiply them with a cosine and a sine wave, respectively. The multiplication works fine but I need an IP to generate the cosine and the sine at a give frequency.

In that purpose, I have deeply read the documentation of the DDS Compiler v6.0 provided at the following link but I am still stuck:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/dds_compiler/v6_0/pg141-dds-compiler.pdf

Does anyone have any suggestion or example code to help me ?

I thank you in advance

### Edit:

Please, find hereunder some screenshots and my example code. What I don't understand is why the sin/cos take theses "strange" values. Did I use the dds_compiler correctly ?

screenshots and Vivado project (I don't have yet the authority to post it directly): https://www.dropbox.com/s/xi5hralr2klk37s/dds_compiler.zip?dl=0

modulator.sv :

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 31.03.2015 07:41:17
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: modulator
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module modulator(
    input  logic        clk,
    input  logic [2:0]  I,
    input  logic [2:0]  Q,
    output logic [18:0] p1,
    output logic [18:0] p2,
    output logic        tvalid
    );

    // internal signals
    logic [15:0] sin,cos;

    // carrier generation
    dds_compiler_0 dds_compiler_0_inst(
        .aclk(clk),
        .m_axis_data_tdata({sin,cos}),
        .m_axis_data_tvalid(tvalid)
    );

    // multiplier
    mult_gen_0 mult_gen_0_inst_1(
        .CLK(clk),
        .A(I),
        .B(cos),
        .P(p1)
    );
    mult_gen_0 mult_gen_0_inst_2(
            .CLK(clk),
            .A(Q),
            .B(sin),
            .P(p2)
        );

endmodule
```

modulator_testbench.sv :

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 31.03.2015 07:41:17
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: modulator_testbench
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module modulator_testbench();

    // test signals
    logic        clk;
    logic [2:0]  I, Q;
    logic [18:0] p1,p2;
    logic        tvalid;

    // generate clock
    always begin clk=1; #5; clk=0; #5; end

    // instantiate dut
    modulator dut(
        .clk(clk),
        .I(I),
        .Q(Q),
        .p1(p1),
        .p2(p2),
        .tvalid(tvalid)
    );

    // start simulation
    initial begin
        #65;
        I=3'd1;  Q=3'd1; #10;
        I=-3'd1; Q=3'd1; #10;
        I=3'd3;  Q=-3'd3; #10;
        I=-3'd3; Q=-3'd1; #10;
        I=3'd1;  Q=-3'd1; #10;
    end

endmodule
```

### Edit II:

For posteriority, the full code is available [here](https://github.com/asonnino/fourier-transmitter); details and explanations can be found in the [paper](https://sonnino.com/papers/figuli2016variable.pdf).

Comment: What exactly does not work? I have used the CORDIC algorithm for generation of sine/cosine and it works perfectly inside a Virtex 5.

Comment: Dear dieli, I thank you for your answer ! I have just edited my question in order to be more specific.

Comment: Seems like the sin and cosine are generated. If I remember correctly, the set phase increment is what is added every clock cycle ("1100" in your case). The phase width (screenshot 1) is 16 bit. Hence, it needs about 5461 clock cycles for one sine/cosine. With 100MHz system frequency you should get 18.3kHz frequency for your sine/cosine. I dont know the Vivado simulator, but you can try to right click on sin[15:0] and view as waveform.

Comment: Thanks ! that solved my problem ! I was confused by the digital waveform but I could get it with analogue view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything worked fine thanks to the comment of dieli. I summary it here in case it could help someone else:

The set phase increment ("1100" in my case) is added every clock cycle. Therefore, since I use a 16-bit bus, I need about 5461 clock cycles for one sin/cos. We can then easily compute the output frequency using the formula given in the datasheet.
To see the sin/cos wave with Vivado, right-click on the sin/cos signal and select 'waveform style' and then 'Analog'. 
(Be sure that you run the simulation for enough time.)